# How to print list with comma separators without spaces?

Tags: python

I need to print list with commas without spaces and enclosed with 2 curly brackets. My code:

```
x = [1,3,6,7]

x = set(x)

print('{', *x, "}", sep=',')
```

This prints:

```
{,1,3,6,7,}
```

I need it to be like this:

```
{1,3,6,7}
```

Comment: ','.join(iterable) https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it has spaces btw commas

Comment: What's the actual problem here? _Why_ do you want to print a list in this way? Note that the conversion to set may change the order of the items, which might not be what you intend. `print` is currently doing exactly what you asked it to, `sep` is placed between _every_ positional argument.

Comment: Is it also your intention to remove duplicates from the list and potentially affect the output order? If not, why are you using set() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a single f-string as follows:

```
_list = [1, 3, 6, 7]

print(f"{{{','.join(map(str, _list))}}}")
```

**Output:**

```
{1,3,6,7}
```

**Note:**

This also ensures that all elements in the original list are retained and presented in the order in which they exist in the list. Using a set could lose data and/or change order

Answer (score 1):

Close. You can't use sep if the brackets are also positional arguments, because it puts the sep between ALL the positional arguments. However, you can use a different print statement.

```
x = [1,3,6,7]

print('{', end='')
print(*x, sep=',', end='')
print('}')
```

But the usual way to join things into a string is with the join method of str. But you need strings, so map str:

```
x = [1,3,6,7]
print('{' + ','.join(map(str, x)) + '}')
```

Answer (score 0):

More symmetric variant:

```
x = [1, 3, 6, 7]
x = set(x)
print('{{{}}}'.format(','.join(str(i) for i in x)))
```

Output:

```
{1,3,6,7}
```

Comment: This doesn't work very well for the list [1, 3, 3, 6, 7]

Comment: @DarkKnight OP already use x = set(x) in the original question

Comment: that is true but it should not be used in a general solution. OP is clearly confused by that fact that the repr output for a set includes leading and trailing braces

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) method and [`map()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) function. Here is the code:

```
x = [1,3,6,7]

x = set(x)

print('{' + ','.join(map(str, x)) + '}')
```

You change every element in `x` to `str` because `.join()` do not work with integers.

Output:
`{1,3,6,7}`

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Format the string to be printed out first:

```
x = [1,3,6,7]
x = set(x)
formatted = "{" + ",".join(map(str, x)) + "}"
print(formatted)
```